# How to make a view gone on scrolling in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a view which i want to scroll up on my tableview scrolling.

[image]

this is the view which will scroll up whenever i am scrolling my tableview. but this is what happens when i do that:

[image]

As u can see there is a black space in between my targeted view and the tableview.

on my **scrollViewDidScroll** i did this:

```
CGPoint offset = scrollView.contentOffset;
    self.counter = 0;
    CGRect bounds = scrollView.bounds;



    CGSize size = scrollView.contentSize;
    UIEdgeInsets inset = scrollView.contentInset;
    float y = offset.y + bounds.size.height - inset.bottom;
    float h = size.height;
    float reload_distance = 10;


    float scrollViewHeight = scrollView.frame.size.height;
    float scrollContentSizeHeight = scrollView.contentSize.height;
    float scrollOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    self.tableData.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;

    if (scrollOffset == 0)
    {
        [self.topView removeFromSuperview];

        [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];


        [self changeHeight:48];
        self.parentOfPhotoview.frame =CGRectMake(0, 0, self.parentOfPhotoview.frame.size.width, self.heightConstraint.constant);

    }
    else if(scrollOffset>2)
    {

        //[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
        //[self.view addSubview:_topView];
        if(self.heightConstraint.constant<2)
        {
            [self changeHeight:0];
        }
        else
        {
        [self changeHeight:48-(scrollView.contentOffset.y)];
        self.parentOfPhotoview.frame = CGRectMake(0, -scrollView.contentOffset.y, self.parentOfPhotoview.frame.size.width, self.heightConstraint.constant);
            self.parentOfPhotoview.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        NSLog(@"%f",self.heightConstraint.constant);
        }




    }

    else if (scrollOffset + scrollViewHeight == scrollContentSizeHeight)
    {
        // then we are at the end
    }
```

**scrolloffset** 0 indicates top and the **heightConstraint** is the height constraint of **parentOfPhotoview** which is the desired view!!

**What is i am missing??**

Answer (score 0):

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
return 0;
}
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return 0;
}
```

Try above line of code. May be your problem will be solved.

Comment: This will just make your table header and rows have no height, that has nothing to do with the navigation bar

Comment: There is black space in between my targeted view and the tableview. So this may be reason.

Comment: The black space is caused by the navigation bar no longer being there and thus having NO view. Hence the black.

Answer (score 0):

You should set your table contentInset with the Top having the same height as the navigationBar. The black is when there is no views at all. This way you do not need to worry about changing height of the tableView etc.

However, I would suggest using AutoLayout.

Also if you want to have parentPhotoView to be floating on the top of the table. You set that in the view for header in section.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

And make sure you set the height of header in section to be the same as the parentPhotoView

Comment: navigation bar is there, my targeted view is just under it,and i am using autolayout.

Comment: isn't there any way to push my Tableview up to fill up the empty space?? @mashdup