# How to push up a view to fill up the empty space in ios

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to push my tableview up so that it can fill up the dark space. Check the link to understand the problem:

[How to make a view gone on scrolling in ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37461701/how-to-make-a-view-gone-on-scrolling-in-ios/37462503#37462503)

i just don't want that empty space

Comment: Set frame of tableView to take the position that you want

Comment: Mention your problem properly with require information

Comment: @Fay007 : Could not make much sense out of the screen shot you attached in question. Put the complete screen image and clarify your requirement

Comment: Exsctly,Put whole screenshot and necessary code in this question

Comment: check again, updated )

Comment: What is the background color of your root view ?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a outlet of Top constraint and set the top constraint value zero when table view load.

Comment: can u please explain it?? @Saurabh jain

Answer (score 0):

I think you have set `clear color` in somewhere in root views. debug view hierarchy and check which view is there at place where you found black color.

It is `clear color` i think. set your desired color to rootview which is shown behing when scroll.

If you don't want that space then make top constraint's constant to `0` when scroll!! and reset constant when scroll down